# Regex validator Symfony 3 with constant as pattern

Tags: php, symfony, validation, yaml

I want to validate a property of one entity using a regex validator.

The regex pattern  I'm using is centralised in a constant located inside a Entity. The reason that this is like that is because I'm using that pattern in other places.

I got to this solution that works perfectly fine.

```
# AppBundle\Entity\Entity
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('foo', new Assert\Regex([
        'pattern' => MyEntity::REGEX_PATTERN,
        'message' => 'bar',
    ]
    ));
}
```

The only problem is that util now all my validation was configured in YAML files. Not that I don't like the current solution but this would mean a change of pattern in my source code.

The question is. Do you know a way to load a Entity constant as the pattern for a Regex assertion in YAML files?

I tyed something like that but didn't worked.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Entity:
    properties:
        foo:
            - Regex:
                pattern: !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity::REGEX_PATTERN
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Empty regular expression
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

With Symfony 3.2.9

Any Ideas?

Comment: *„but didn't work“* what was the error?

Comment: I got this error: Warning: preg_match(): Empty regular expression
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Comment: Your symfony version is >= 3.2? https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files

Comment: @Chris yes, Symfony 3.2.9

Comment: What's the value of `REGEX_PATTERN`?